# multidimensional array in php codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I need to build a multidimensional array from records retrieved from my database.

Here is the code I have:

```
<?php
/*
 ...some code...
 */
foreach($data['colleges'] as $college)
{
  $college_temp[] =  $college->name; 
  $college_temp[] =  $college->abbrev;
  $college_temp[] =  $college->long_name;
  $college_temp[] =  $college->long_abbrev;
  $college_temp[] =  $college->url;
  $college_temp[] =  $college->description;
}
```

All the records from the database are going one after the other in the array. I need to optimize this using a multidimensional array.

Comment: What should be the structure of your multidimensional array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$college_temp = array();
foreach($data['colleges'] as $college)
{
    $college_temp[] =  $college;
}

// Echo the first one's name
echo $college_temp[0]['name'];

// Echo the second one's url
echo $college_temp[1]['url'];
```

Comment: i want to pass that array using json_encode.. and then also retrieve it using decode

Answer (score 1):

```
$college_temp = array();
$i = 0;
foreach($data['colleges'] as $college)
    {

        $college_temp[$i]['name'] =  $college->name; 
        $college_temp[$i]['abbrev'] =  $college->abbrev;
        $college_temp[$i]['long_name'] =  $college->long_name;
        $college_temp[$i]['long_abbrev'] =  $college->long_abbrev;
        $college_temp[$i]['url'] =  $college->url;
        $college_temp[$i]['description'] =  $college->description;
        $i++;

    }
    // var_dump($college_temp); // uncomment to check array contents
```